# How can to get the filename from a streaming mapreduce job in R?

Tags: r, hadoop, environment-variables, filenames, hadoop-streaming

I am streaming an R mapreduce job and I am need to get the filename. I know that Hadoop sets environment variables for the current job before it starts and I can access env vars in R with Sys.getenv().

I found :
[Get input file name in streaming hadoop program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449756/get-input-file-name-in-streaming-hadoop-program)

and Sys.getenv(mapred_job_id) works fine, but it is not what I need. I just need the filename and not the job id or name. I also found: [How to get filename when running mapreduce job on EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074730/how-to-get-filename-when-running-mapreduce-job-on-ec2)

But this isn't helpful either. What is the easiest way to get the current filename while streaming from R? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried this, but from the second link you provided, it seems that this is available in an environment variable called `map.input.file`. Then, this should work:

```
Sys.getenv("map.input.file")
```

EDIT:
Upon further investigation, I learned that you need to replace the dots with underscores, so this is the way to do it:

```
Sys.getenv("map_input_file")
```

However, [the map.input.file property has been deprecated in YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html) (Hadoop 2.x), so the new name should be used instead:

```
Sys.getenv("mapreduce_map_input_file")
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I think it is because that post is using an elastic mapreduce from Amazon which has additional support. I also tried "map_input_file" and it had the exact same result.

Comment: @jason Are you using YARN? If so, you should use the new property name. See my updated answer.

Comment: I figured it out. "map_input_file" was working correctly, but its returning the full path and that is causing things to break and that's why my job is crashing. Thanks for your help.